# deleting file in ntfs using c

Tags: c, winapi

How can I delete a file on an ntfs drive? i tried deletefile and remove, but neither worked. Any suggestions?

```
do { 
  char* nPtr = new char [lstrlen( data.cFileName ) + 1]; 

  for( int i = 0; i < lstrlen( data.cFileName ); i++ ) 
    nPtr[i] = char( data.cFileName[i] ); 

  nPtr[lstrlen( data.cFileName )] = '\0'; 

  if(!strcmp(nPtr , fn)) 
    remove(nPtr); 

  cout << nPtr << endl; 
}
```

thanks arefin

Comment: What "didn't work" about it? Did you get an error? did you check what what the error meant?

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: "i tried deletefile and remove but they didn't work." <-- How so? The correct syscall *is* [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915.aspx).

Comment: DeleteFile is correct on Windows. It **does** work, but you did something wrong. Did you have an error message? How did the behaviour differ from what you wanted?

Comment: i tried deleteFile(filename) which returns 0 and the remove(filename ) returns -1 thus they didnt work.

Comment: do
  {
   char*   nPtr = new char [lstrlen( data.cFileName ) + 1];
   for( int i = 0; i < lstrlen( data.cFileName ); i++ )
    nPtr[i] = char( data.cFileName[i] );

   nPtr[lstrlen( data.cFileName )] = '\0';
   if(!strcmp(nPtr , fn))
    remove(nPtr);
   cout << nPtr << endl;

  }

Comment: @Nobody: If you say "they didn't work" one more time I will slap you in the face. That phrase is _meaningless_.

Comment: @Nobody: Did you call GetLastError to find out what the error was?

Comment: @Nobody: Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @tomalak .. deleteFile function returns 0 and remove function returns -1

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081

Comment: Erm, I don't see anywhere in the code you posted where you call the `DeleteFile` function. What am I missing here?

Comment: i tried both the deleteFile and then remove ..  as i cudnt delete the file using the deleteFile so i used remove here . its a part of a function.

Comment: @all can anybody explain me why -3 votes before i voted up.What is the criteria that the users in stackoverflow use to downvote a questio/answer.i have been for around 1 month (although i am a memeber since5 monhs) but i have seen downvoting without any solid reason.And upvoting also to those questions of users with higher points.I do not want an articulated answer.

Comment: thanks algorithmist .. i cudnt find a solution may be it was my fault but i really tried my best to solve the problem and here i found that people gave me negative vote instead of answering the problem. may b i shud try by myself instead of asking in stackoverflow

Comment: @Nobody: Did you call GetLastError to find out what the error was? The page I linked you to -- which is the documentation for DeleteFile, so you should already have read it back-to-front before attempting to use the function -- says, quite clearly: "If the function fails, the return value is zero (0). To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: @Algorithmist: It's a poorly stated question which amounts to little more than "I did not use any error checking; please do it for me." No-one else is going to get anything out of this question, but this is a programming community rather than a support forum. That's why it's been voted down.

Comment: @Algorithmist: The tooltip for the downvote button says "This question is unclear or not useful". I think this one qualifies as both. The original didn't even have the code that has been tried posted, yet it complained that some code didn't work. No details were given about *how* it didn't work, and the problem wasn't reproducible. When pressed for sample code, the problem is still not reproducible because it doesn't even include a call to the function that supposedly "doesn't work". We still don't know what "doesn't work" means, and the OP resists requests to try troubleshooting himself.

Comment: @Tomalak ,@cody a user posts his query expecting that somebody would help him to overcome his difficulty.But this unneccesary downvoting makes one feel dejected as expressed by nobody and would make a user refrain from posting his questions and doubts.Also i don't think so @nobody mentioned that he wants the code or the complete solution.That's not good as far as stack overflow is concerned.Also you didn't answered my other quetion.Please see my comment.

Comment: @Algorithmist: StackOverflow is not here to make you feel better about yourself. It is a programming Q&A community. Please read the FAQ and entertain further philosophical discussions on what you think SO should and should not be in the meta.stackoverflow.com chatrooms. Thanks

Comment: @Algorithmist: In addition to what Tomalak says about Stack Overflow not being here to help you feel better about yourself, also consider that downvotes are explicitly *not personal*. You downvote questions and answers, not people. This question is neither useful nor clear, thus it deserves every downvote it's accumulated. I'm surprised it hasn't started to accumulate *close* votes. No one said they were voting the question down because he asked for "the code". The question is being voted down because it's not clear and not useful. It's impossible to answer with the information given.

Comment: @Algorithmist What's not good is not paying attention. As Cody said, "The original didn't even have the code that has been tried posted". The downvotes were made before that code was added. Go look at the edit and see just how bad this question was before being edited. Then get off your high horse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to [`DeleteFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28VS.85%29.aspx) does work and in your case it did work.

`DeleteFile()` is contracted to delete the file you specify, if it can be deleted.  If the file could be deleted, then it will be. If the file could not be deleted then it will not be.

If `DeleteFile()` returns false, what the documentation refers to as *failure*, then the file was not deleted, for a good reason.  You can call [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find out why the file was not deleted.

Answer (score 3):

"didn't work" can happen because mistake in parameter (path specified not correctly) or because you don't have  permissions to delete the file or because the file is in use. Resolutions are different for these causes. You can check what the actual problem is by checking whether DeleteFile() returns false and then calling GetLastError() function to get the error code. 
Error codes:

2 - file not found
  3 - path not found
  5 - access denied
  87 - invalid parameter

Comment: i searched in google and found there that i cant delete file in ntfs file system by using those command

Comment: @Nobody: That article provides a few reasons why you *might* not be able to delete a file on an NTFS partition with the `DeleteFile` command. It doesn't say that you can't *ever* delete such a file. Normally, you can. By checking the error code (using `GetLastError`), you can figure out if you're encountering one of those rare cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: @all can anybody explain me why -3 votes before i voted up.@nobody has not asked for the whole code or has not asked a vague question then why downvoting?.What is the criteria that the users in stackoverflow use to downvote a questio/answer.i have been for around 1 month (although i am a memeber since5 monhs) but i have seen downvoting without any solid reason.And upvoting also to those questions of users with higher points and ignoring questions that of naive users .I do not want an articulated answer.I know this would be reported as spam or would be downvoted as well.

Comment: @Algorithmist the person who asks a question is supposed to put at least minimal effort at solving the problem himself. Good question contains 80% of the answer. So writing a good question is also a valuable work. And if one asks "it doesn't work - why" - there are no oracles here to give an answer based on broken bones or something like that. At least error description is supposed to be present.

Comment: @Algorithmist: That should have been a comment on the question, not on this answer. BTW more experienced users get more upvotes because they write better answers; duh.

Comment: sorry i am new in stackoverflow so i wrote the question in a wrong way. i tried a lot to solve it by myself and finnally when i couldn't solve it i posted it here. from next time i will try my best to write organized question

Comment: @Tomalak this is not always the case my friend.I can elicitate examples form the previous posts where a betterly looking and well formed question was not accepted as the solution or does not have many votes simply because the user was rookie or naive.People just go throuh the reputation.Yes it is a hard and true fact in STACKOVERFLOW.

Comment: @Algorithmist: Entertain further discussion on this topic in the meta.stackoverflow.com chatrooms please. And quit stating "facts": you are not the great and almighty powerful imperious leader who knows all; this is a community.

Comment: @Algorithmist such discussion should go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com yet I suspect it has been discussed there a number of times.

Comment: @Tomalak stopping discussion now but i have not said anywhere that i am tyrannical or haughty or arrogant leader.

Comment: "I do not want an articulated answer.I know this would be reported as spam or would be downvoted as well." In other words, you're a troll.

Comment: "I can elicitate examples form the previous posts where a betterly looking and well formed question was not accepted as the solution or does not have many votes simply because the user was rookie or naive." You cannot know why a vote was made unless the reason is explicitly given. "People just go throuh the reputation.Yes it is a hard and true fact in STACKOVERFLOW" No, it's obviously a rash generalization based not on evidence but on a whole lotta emotion.